# Graphviz displaying labels along the edge

Tags: graphviz, dot

is there a way to annotate the dot file so that the labels for the edges are shown along the edge ?

Ex: if the edge is at an 45 degree angle, the label should show up at the same angle too

I've tried to use the "lblstyle" and and it didn't work and I would like a method that doesn't use tex

[image]

As shown here the edge labels are all horizontal, I need them to go inline with the edge

Thanks

Comment: I think an example / MWE with image wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Added a picture

Answer (score 1):

That feature is currently  not available, if you really need it I guess you could render to SVG and do some post processing.
Personaly I fallback to the next best thing and put edge[decorate=true] at start of all my graphs. This will draw a line between the text and the edge so you can easier see which edge a label belong to